# "Variation" versus "Variations"

Tags: word-choice

I currently have the following sentence:

> Due to **variations** in how screens display color, actual printed colors may vary slightly.

However, does it make sense to drop the *s*?

> Due to **variation** in how screens display color, actual printed colors may vary slightly.

Comment: I like it better with the S.  If it bothers you, perhaps: "Due to a variation in how screens display color" or "Due to the variation in how screens display color."

Comment: FWIW, I picture something a bit different with and without the s. Without it, I picture a central reference point with each screen's color clustered around it. In the plural, I picture several distinct clusters - there might be some screens with a particularly blue cast, others particularly green, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *variation* would refer to a single specific variation (or screen).  *Variations* (plural) refers to variations in general, so that's the one you want.

[According to ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=due%20to%20variations%20in%2C%20due%20to%20variation%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdue%20to%20variations%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdue%20to%20variation%20in%3B%2Cc0), *due to variations in* is far more prevalent than *due to variation in*.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks for the link to the ngrams tool, very cool!